# Can't save / load iptables rules on Arch Linux via rc.d

Tags: iptables, arch-linux

**I can not load my saved iptables rules when the server reboots on Arch Linux. Any ideas?**

The latest Arch updates are in place.

I have followed Arch Linux's [tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Iptables)... neither either works. The following **do work** via the prompt as `root` user:

***1.** iptables-save & restore*

```
/usr/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/iptables.rules
```

***2.** rc.d*

```
rc.d start iptables
```

I have even attempted to run below as a cron on `root` with no joy:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/bash /usr/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/iptables.rules > /home/me/boot-iptables.log
```

Surely I am missing something... everyone must be doing this*?

**By 'this' I mean wanting privileged port 80 going to 8080. I am going the wrong route for the simplest, cleanest way to do so? Everything was so good till now PacMan.*

Comment: `rc.d` has been deprecated for quite a long time. Could you try `systemctl enable iptables.service` and reboot afterwards?

Comment: Still not working unfortunately. I thought rc.d was deprecated, but its not fully be transitioned out.

Comment: It is unsupported and parts of it may break at any time.
You *really* should switch to systemd

Comment: Have you added `iptables` to the `DAEMONS` array in `/etc/rc.conf`?

Comment: @t-8ch no... I've not...

Comment: @t-8ch that's it, it works.

Comment: @t-8ch (this comment is not directed at you of course) It's a little frustrating that this is not mentioned in the arch wiki. I've been drawn to arch by the cleanest of its setup. I get that its moving to systemd, but the distro I am using and all the pacman updates don't move me over to it automagically (there's a wiki page of warnings for moving to systemd). In experienced I may be... but demonising something that preforms a single action in unintuitive. However, thanks for your help! Do you want to add this as answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the tutorial you followed is written with systemd in mind.
As you are still using the old init system you have to add `iptables` to the `DAEMONS` array in your `rc.conf`.
Please be aware that the next update to the iptables package my drop the `/etc/rc.d/iptables` script.

The old init has been deprecated for some time and is being purged from the wiki and the packages. Do yourself a favor and take the time for a clean migration.